# delegate() a class within TBODY TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm experimenting with `.live()` and `.delegate()` for elements that are added to DOM well after my JS is loaded.

This works:

```
$(".mouseRow tbody tr").live("click", function(event) { });
```

But this does not work and no errors are given, which makes me think it is a DOM timing thing:

```
$(".mouseRow").delegate("tbody tr", "click", function(event) { });
```

Am I calling the `.delegate()` function incorrectly, perhaps with the "`tbody tr`" statement? Or is this a problem with the DOM timing since the elements do not exist yet (which is why I used `live()` in the first place)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If `.mouseRow` is a class you're applying to `tr` elements, you want:</s> You've said in the comments that `mouseRow` is a class on the `table` element within which you want to hook clicks on `tr` elements. If the `table.mouseRow` elements will exist as of when you're hooking up your handlers, you probably want this:

```
$("table.mouseRow tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function(event) { ... });
```

That hooks the `click` event on `tbody` within the `table.mouseRow`, and when it occurs checks the chain of elements from the one actually clicked up to `tbody` to see if any of them match the selector `tr`. If so, it calls the event handler with `this` referencing the row in question.

Or as of jQuery 1.7, the recommendation is to use `on` for this sort of thing:

```
$("table.mouseRow tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event) { ... });
```

(Note that the order of arguments is slightly different.)

Either way, you execute that statement when the `table.mouseRow tbody` is already in the DOM. If it won't be there yet, you need to go further up the DOM, perhaps all the way to `document`:

```
$("table.mouseRow tbody tr").live("click", function(event) { ... });
// or (1.7 onward):
$(document).on("click", "table.mouseRow tbody tr", function(event) { ... }));
```

Comment: To preface this: I have little understanding of live() vs. delegate(). I was trying to setup my function with a specific context to take advantage of the performance advantages discussed here: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-function.html  ... do I still get those performance advantages of delegate() over live() how you set it up? And is it always better to use delegate() over live()?

Comment: @themerlinproject: The further up the DOM you hook the actual event (e.g., the closer to `document`), the more work jQuery has to do when the event occurs (checking to see whether the elements in the chain from what you clicked up to the base element match the selector). The greater the distance from the actual element clicked up through its ancestors to the element you've used as the base, the more work is involved. However, note that it's very unlikely to actually matter, I wouldn't worry about it until/unless you have a specific performance problem to solve.

Comment: It is actually the table that has class .mouseRow and I'm looking to activate on a TR click

Comment: @themerlinproject: So the basic rule is: Use the most specific element it's *reasonable* to use. "Reasonable" meaning: It exists in the DOM when you're hooking things up, you're not going to replace it with something else, and logically it makes sense. You'll never see me hook up an event on `document` to handle clicks on table rows; I'll do that on the `tbody` once I add it. You get the idea. :-)

Comment: @themerlinproject: "mouseRow" seems a very odd class name for `table` elements. ;-) I'll update.

Comment: thanks for your help. the logic was: it is a function for the click of any row, but you only have to apply the class to the table instead of each row